# Sqlite:Select query not work

Tags: java, android, split

I have this function.
I pass a String to the function and it splits it in to 2 parts.Then i am going to use the *a[1]* in my **select query** and it allways return me **null**. Finally i made my mind to print the  `query String` and it was in this way :

```
select *  from targettree where target='t

    '
```

and as you know it should be in this way

```
    select *  from targettree where target='t'
```

Here is the function:

```
 protected void fun(String statment) 
 {
    String[] a=statment.split("  ");



    String t=a[1].toString();
    String query = "select *  from targettree where target='"+t+"'";
    Select(query);

}
```

So is it happen because of `split("  ")` or is there any other reason?

Comment: Post your `Select` function code.

Comment: The select function always works. i have already checked it. The problem is lead by the string

Comment: Use prepared statements whenever you can. Sanitize inputs anyway.

Comment: you are obviously using rawQuery. use query instead, with '?' parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing

```
String query = "select *  from targettree where target='"+t+"'";
```

with

```
String query = "select *  from targettree where target='"+t.trim()+"'";
```

Comment: @AReader-Really thanks man. And plz UP vote me because i believe i have asked a correct and useful question.